# XmlSerializer throws a StackOverflowException on deserialization but only if it is called from an ASMX web service

Tags: c#, asmx, xmlserializer

I have a c# solution with an ASMX startup project and having also some other projects. One of these projects (say `ThirdProject`) has a class (say `DataReader`) with a method (say `ReadData()`) which performs a deserialization of a stream. The stream itself is OK, it comes from an embedded resource, and it can be read without error by a StreamReader to a string, and it is really a valid xml string. But the deserialization throws a StackOverflowException.

Now comes the weirdness. For test purposes, I've created an additional project to this c# solution, this is a winform project. If I set this winform project to be the startup project of the solution, then it calls the `ThirdProject.DataReader. ReadData()` procedure without any error! The deserialization completes!

I've repeated my expreiments by changing the bitness (x86 or x64), and also by changing the target .Net Framework (from 4.0 to 4.7.2), but the result is always the same.

Where should I search the cause of this error? Any hint would be appreciated.

**Edit**.

The code part in question is this:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xmlname))
{
    var l = stream.Length;
    var ret_obj = ktAntragsdatenAbrufenXmlFormat.Deserialize(stream);
    ...
}
```

The stream.Length is 18671. The `ktAntragsdatenAbrufenXmlFormat` is a static `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`

This code part runs without error:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xmlname))
{
    var l = stream.Length;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Where is the xml file located?  It sounds like the service cannot get access top the xml file.  When a user connects to the server it has limited access to the files on the server.  Make sure the service is reading the file from the client machine.

Comment: The xml file is embedded into the ThirdProject.dll. Since the StreamReader can read it, I think that it has nothing to do with the clients.

Comment: Is it possible that your stream source isn't properly closing and flushing the stream? Could you be deserializing while it is still writing?  Could you show the part of your code that reads from the stream and deserializes?  How big is the data being deserialized?

Comment: I've copied the code into the post. The length of the stream is 18671 byes.

Comment: Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: No, it is null. HResult = -2147023895. I told that the xml is small, but the xsd files are pretty big. They are at least 5 MBytes. Can it be a problem? If yes, then why only when it is called from the asmx.cs?

Comment: Useful stack depth on ASP.Net is less even with identical settings because there is a lot of infrastructure code that already takes some stack space... So if your deserialization code just needs a lot of stack space it may barely pass in console code but fail in ASP.Net...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Should I create a new thread for this method to get more stack space? Or do you have better idea?

Comment: You should figure out if that is actually the problem first - maybe by experimenting with smaller stack size in your console app... There really no reason why deserialization of small *static* XML file need to be so complicated (and you really should reconsider having XSD for it - validate/expand entities  during build if you have to)

Answer (score 0):

Since `reader.ReadToEnd()` seems to work fine, try the following:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xmlname))
{
    var l = stream.Length;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(text))
    {
        var ret_obj = ktAntragsdatenAbrufenXmlFormat.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if you have a valid xml it can have referrence loops.
If your web service is json, you can set a reference loop handling strategy like ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore somewhere, havent used that, but there must be an option for that. 
If its not json, it just wont go through your webservice as XML, i have no idea if an option even exists in that case. You possibly have to get rid of ref. loops manually before sending and rebuild them once its arrived on the other side.

Nvm, its not your case... ill leave it here anyway

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that reference loops are causing the error, because the deserialization is successful when it is called from a desktop project.